# Why aren't my HTTP caching headers working?

Tags: .net, http, httpwebrequest, http-caching

I recently added some HTTP caching headers to some of my web service's responses, but they so far haven't done anything for me on the client side.  Here's one of these responses:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/vnd.com...
Expires: Thu, 27 Sep 2012 03:40:27 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: DDRSSID=...
X-DDVS-Version: 1.0.0.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2012 03:40:22 GMT
```

According to both Fiddler and REDbot, this response should be entirely cacheable.  Here's what Fiddler says:

> public: This response MAY be cached by any cache.
>   max-age: This resource will expire in 1 minutes. [60 sec]

Even so, the responses are not coming from cache: I see them in Fiddler and the `IsFromCache` property on my `HttpWebResponse` is **false**.  Here's the content of my request, fwiw:

```
GET http://floater/rest/folders/folder.20 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.com....
Authorization: Basic blahblah
Host: floater
```

What am I missing?

Comment: From what I know, those caching settings are only _recommendations_ to the browser, not mandatory. Plus, you may have (proxy) servers between your server and the client that also may interpret/override the caching headers other than you intended.

Comment: @UweKeim: 'floater' is the name of my local machine, and I am sometimes using Fiddler as a proxy.  I understand caching isn't mandatory, but I'm not asking why my packets aren't being cached 100% of the time; I'm asking why they are being cached *0% of the time!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there wasn't anything wrong with my headers.  Rather, the problem was that the default caching policy for [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.cachepolicy.aspx) is *not* [`HttpRequestCacheLevel.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cache.httprequestcachelevel.aspx).  My bad, I guess.

By adding the following line to my request initialization I was able to see the caching results I expected:

```
webRequest.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Default);
```

Another problem I had while testing this in various respects was that responses are not cached unless you read the entire response (eg. by reading to the end of [GetResponseStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream.aspx)).  This is thankfully noted in the documentation:

> A copy of a resource is only added to the cache if the response stream for the resource is retrieved and read to the end of the stream.